# Change production exchange in an activity

Tags: activity-lifecycle, brightway

How can we replace the production exchange in an activity with a technosphere exchange already present in this activity?

In an activity `act`, I tried to do it by deleting the existing production exchange `existing_prod_exc` and then create a new production exchange using `new_prod_exc=act.new_exchange(input=act.key,output=act.key,type='production')` but I don't know how to "copy" all the exchange characteristics of the existing exchange `techno_exc` into `new_prod_exc`.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply directly change the exchange you are interested in and save it:

```
exc_to_become_production['type'] = 'production'
exc_to_become_production['input'] = exc_to_become_production['output']
exc_to_become_production.save()
```

Doing just this will result in two production exchanges. You can then delete the existing production exchange if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the exchange type can be accomplished in several ways; you could directly edit the `type` column in the SQLite database, or work with the `ExchangeDataset` objects, but I guess you want to use the main interface. In this case, changing the exchange type is easy:

```
some_exc = next(iter(some_activity.technosphere()))
some_exc['type'] = 'production'
some_exc.save()
```

Recall that the only difference between an input and an output is the [sign of the value in the technosphere matrix](https://chris.mutel.org/non-unitary.html); you can accomplish the same thing therefore by multiplying the sign of the exchange amount by -1.

I guess you would also want to delete the existing production exchange (you should do this first, for obvious reasons!):

```
for exc in some_activity.production():
    exc.delete()
```

As in any destructive operation, it is best to try this first on a copy of actual data; you can create a test project quickly using `projects.copy_project()`.